# Find the all the pairs $(n,m) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ with the property that $ 2^n+3^m $ is divisible by $23$.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the all the pairs $(n,m) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ with the property that $ 2^n+3^m $ is divisible by $23$.

I'm not really sure how to start this one, but since I found it in a book on group theory, such an approach might also be possible.

Comment: why group theory?

Comment: purely speculative, but I was considering that maybe a solution using residue classes would be possible

Comment: I dont think modulo would help much.... can you write the details where you encountered this? any back round? what are the things you can make use of ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Powers of two modulo $23$: $1,2,4,8,16,9,18,13,3,6,12,1 \ldots$
Powers of three modulo $23$: $1,3,9,4,12,13,16,2,6,18,8,1\ldots$
Find all the pairs $(n,m)$ such that $n$ is in the first set and $m$ is in the second, with $n+m=23$.

Comment: This does makes some sense :) I am not saying it is doable but it is good looking and more natural :D

Comment: Agreed, less to calculate.

Comment: But, do you think, this is a solution or should it be posted as a comment?

Comment: It's easy to see there are no solutions by just taking an $n$ from the first row and seeing that there are no $m$ in the second row equal to $23-n$. So, take $1$, see there is no $22$. Take $2$, see there is no $21$, and so on.

Comment: this works okay, thanks :)

Comment: Can you ultimately say that until you find the residue to be periodic?

Comment: But I have found the residue to be periodic, and by Fermat's Little Theorem we know it would take at most $22$ terms for it to be.

Comment: Okay,this works...Great...

Answer (score 4):

As $\displaystyle 2^3\cdot3=24\equiv1\pmod{23},$

$\displaystyle 2^n+3^m\equiv0\pmod{23}\iff 2^{n+3m}\equiv-3^m\cdot2^{3m}\equiv-(3\cdot2^3)^m$

$\displaystyle\implies2^{n+3m}\equiv-1\pmod{23}$

Now as $23$ is prime, $\displaystyle a^2\equiv1,a\equiv\pm1\pmod{23}$ for $(a,23)=1$

and $\displaystyle2^5=32\equiv9,2^{10}\equiv9^2=81\equiv12,2^{11}\equiv2\cdot12\equiv1$

So, there is no integer exponent$(e)$ of $2$ such that $2^e\equiv-1\pmod{23}$

Hence, the system admits no solution in integers

---

Alternatively,

HINT:

As $3^3\equiv2^2\pmod{23},$

Case $1:$ If $\displaystyle m=3r+1,2^n+3^m=2^n+3^{3r+1}\equiv 2^n+3\cdot2^{2r}\pmod{23}$

So, we need $\displaystyle 2^{n-2r}\equiv-3\pmod{23}$

Observe that there is no integer exponent$(e)$ of $2$ such that $2^e\equiv-3\pmod{23}$

Case $2:$ If $\displaystyle m=3r+2$

Case $3:$ If $\displaystyle m=3r$

Comment: what next? can you reach some conclusion from here?

Comment: @Hawk, please find the edited version. I could not update the answer as I was on my way home

Comment: yes...it is a solution...but I was expecting some solution with hands-on approach.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Look up Fermat's little theorem.

**Solution**:

We are looking for $n,m$ such that $2^n+3^m\equiv 0$ modulo $23$. By Fermat's little theorem $2^{22}\equiv 3^{22}\equiv 1$. Thus it only remains to check the pairs $(n,m)$ with $0\le n,m<22$. This is just $484$ numbers therefore it can be done with a computer, e.g. using Wolfram alpha with

```
Table[mod(2^n+3^m,23)=0,{n,0,21},{m,0,21}]
```

It returns a huge table with the entries only being *False*, therefore there are no natural numbers $n,m$ such that $2^n+3^m$ is divisible by $23$.

Comment: No idea how would FLT would help :O

Comment: It reduces the problem to only $484$ pairs of $n,m$ which you then can check by a computer.

Comment: could you please expand on that solution?

Comment: fine... No comments... I was expecting a more theoretical way.... well done anyways :)

Comment: Using Wolfram Alpha,to provide a math solution? Is that okay?

Comment: @Hawk :  It is alright to use wolfram alpha to make some sense out of that but i would not suggest to do that at first sight!

Comment: If it was the ultimate goal to solve problems using a computer, then why try to solve anything at all? Let computers do it, we should just sit and look?

Comment: It simply saves time. If problems are actually so easy that we can have a computer do them, then why waste our own time on them?

Comment: I understand how this method works, my only confusion is that I'm certain this problem was also given at a contest. At a competition you can't really evaluate all the 484 pairs. Is there a way to prove that there are actually no such pairs in a method feasible to be done on paper?

Comment: Definitely there is. See the other two answers.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose a solution to $2^{n}\equiv-3^m$ (everything in this answer is $\pmod {23}$.) I'll show that this implies $-2$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod {23}$, which is false.

**Lemma.** $n$ is odd.

Firstly, we know $3\equiv 7^2$, so $2^{n}\equiv-7^{2m}$. Now, the inverse of two $2^{-1}$ is $\equiv 12$, so $-1\equiv7^{2m}12^{n}$. If $n$ were even, $-1$ would be a quadratic residue $\pmod {23}$, which is false.

---

Set $n=2k+1$. This implies $-2\equiv 7^{2m}12^{2k}=\left(7^m12^k\right)^2$, so $-2$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod {23}$, but this is false. Therefore, there are no solutions $(m, n)$.

Comment: See also my answer for a related quadratic residue viewpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $\ {\rm mod}\ 23\!:\  3\equiv 1/8\equiv \color{#0a0}{2^{-3}},\ \ 2\equiv 5^2\Rightarrow\ 2^{11}\equiv 5^{22}\equiv \color{#c00}1\,$ by $\,\mu$Fermat.  Therefore

$$ 2^{\large n} \equiv -3^{\large m} \equiv -\color{#0a0}{2^{\large -3\color{black}{\large m}}}\ \Rightarrow\ 2^{\large n+3m}\equiv -1\smash{\overset{\large\ (\ \ )^{11}}\Rightarrow} \color{#c00}1 \equiv -1 \,\Rightarrow\,\Leftarrow\qquad\  $$

**Remark** $\ $ Alternatively, note $\, 3\equiv 7^2$ so $\ 3^{11}\equiv 7^{22}\equiv 1$ hence $\ 2^n \equiv -3^m\smash{\overset{\large\ (\ \ )^{11}}\Rightarrow}1\equiv -1.\ $ Therefore, the proof essentially boils down to the fact that the product of the two squares $2^n$ and $3^{-m}$ cannot equal $-1$ since it is not a square (by Euler's Criterion)